# Ubuntu update manager error & Ubuntu internal error

Tags: update-manager

I'm using Lenovo B460e laptop 2gb ddr3 ram ,Dual core processor,Ubuntu 32bit os

When opening update manager the following error occurs
'E:Type 'wnloader' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jd-team-jdownloader-precise.list' can anyone help

Comment: Can you post the contents of your sources.list? Something like: cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jd-team-jdownloader-precise.list

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jd-team/jdownloader && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install jdownloader && sudo apt-get upgrade
```